# Add items to MongoDB Array with Datanucleus

Tags: java, arrays, mongodb, datanucleus, updating

I know that you can add array items to a MongoDB document by doing something like:

`db.mycollection.update( {"id":"asd"}, {"$pushAll" : {array_name: [1, 2, 3]}} )`

How can you do this with Datanucleus? I've looked through the documentation and searched around, but haven't been able to find out if Datanucleus supports it.

Currently I'm pulling the whole document out, adding the item, then re-adding the whole document to MongoDB.

Answer (score 0):

By using Datanucleus, you are managing your objects as POJOs. Check [this page](http://datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_3_3/jdo/guides/tutorial_mongodb.html) for more information.

Is the code you mentioned, pure mongo API ?